# C program won't compile without warnings when GCC is called by makefile - Works otherwise

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So I have a program here, that works perfectly when called with

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -std=c99
```

But when called in a makefile:

```
all: test

test: test.c
    gcc test.c -o test -std=c99
```

it produces some warnings instead and gives a segmentation fault.

terminal output:

```
gcc -g test.c -o tester -std=c99
test.c: In function ‘test_split’:
test.c:43:2: warning: implicit declaration of function‘strdup[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  char *str_cpy = strdup(str); // Allow mutation of original string
test.c:43:18: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  char *str_cpy = strdup(str); // Allow mutation of original string
```

Above error does not appear otherwise and does not produse a segmentation fault.

The code segment that fails is here. string.h is included in header.
The file is just a large file to test other functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define CNRM "\x1b[0m" 
#define CRED "\x1b[31m"
#define CGRN "\x1b[32m"

int stringsum(char *s);
void stringsum2(char *s, int *res);
int distance_between(char *s, char c);
char *string_between(char *s, char c);
char **split(char *s);

static int test_num = 1;

static void logger(int passed, char *s)
{
    char *res;
    char *color;

if (passed) {
    res = "PASS";
    color = CGRN;
} else {
    res = "FAIL";
    color = CRED;
}
printf("[Test %d][%s%s%s] %s\n", test_num++, color, res, CNRM, s);
}

static void test_split(char *str, char **correct)
{
int i, pass = 1;
char buf[512] = { 0 };
char *str_cpy = strdup(str); // Allow mutation of original string
char **res = split(str_cpy);

if (!res || !res[0]) {
    pass = 0;
    sprintf(buf, "split() returned NULL or an empty array");
    goto end;
}

for (i = 0; correct[i]; i++) {
    if (!res[i]) {
        pass = 0;
        sprintf(buf, "split() returned fewer words than expected");
        goto end;
    }
}

if (res[i]) {
    pass = 0;
    sprintf(buf, "split() returned more words than expected");
    goto end;
}

sprintf(buf, "\n%-16s%-16s\n", "Returned", "Expected");

for (i = 0; res[i]; i++) {
    char tmp[256] = { 0 };
    sprintf(tmp, "%-16s%-16s\n", res[i], correct[i]);
    strcat(buf, tmp);
    if (strcmp(res[i], correct[i])) {
        pass = 0;
        goto end;
    }
}

end:
logger(pass, buf);
free(str_cpy);
}

static void test_stringsum(char *input, int expected)
{
int test;
char buf[256] = { 0 };

test = stringsum(input);
sprintf(buf, "Returned: %d, Expected: %d", test, expected);
logger(test == expected, buf);
}

static void test_distance_between(char *str, char c, int expected)
{
int test;
char buf[256] = { 0 };

test = distance_between(str, c);
sprintf(buf, "Returned: %d, Expected: %d", test, expected);
logger(test == expected, buf);
}

static void test_string_between(char *str, char c, const char *expected)
{
char *res_char;
char buf[256] = { 0 };

res_char = string_between(str, c);
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Returned: %s, Expected: %s", res_char, expected);

if (!res_char && expected) {
    logger(0, buf);
} else {
    if (!expected)
        logger(!res_char, buf);
    else
        logger(!strcmp(res_char, expected), buf);
    free(res_char);
}
}

static void test_stringsum2(char *input, int expected)
{
int res_int;
char buf[256] = { 0 };

stringsum2(input, &res_int);
sprintf(buf, "Returned: %d, Expected: %d", res_int, expected);
logger(res_int == expected, buf);
}

int main(void)
{
printf("Testing stringsum()\n");
test_stringsum("abcd", 10);
test_stringsum("a!", -1);
test_stringsum("aAzZ", 54);
test_stringsum("ababcDcabcddAbcDaBcabcABCddabCddabcabcddABCabcDd", 120);
test_stringsum("", 0);

test_num = 1;
printf("\nTesting distance_between()\n");
test_distance_between("a1234a", 'a', 5);
test_distance_between("a1234", 'a', -1);
test_distance_between("123456a12334a123a", 'a', 6);
test_distance_between("", 'a', -1);

test_num = 1;
printf("\nTesting string_between()\n");
test_string_between("a1234a", 'a', "1234");
test_string_between("a1234", 'a', NULL);
test_string_between("A123adette er svaretaasd2qd3asd12", 'a', "dette er sv");
test_string_between("", 'a', NULL);

test_num = 1;
printf("\nTesting stringsum2()\n");
test_stringsum2("abcd", 10);
test_stringsum2("abcd!", -1);
test_stringsum2("bbbdbbbbbdbbdbbbbbddbbbbbdbbdbbbbdbd", 90);
test_stringsum2("", 0);

test_num = 1;
printf("\nTesting split()\n");
test_split("abcd", (char *[]){ "abcd", NULL });
test_split("Hei du", (char *[]){ "Hei", "du", NULL });
test_split("Dette er mange ord", (char *[]){ "Dette", "er", "mange", "ord", NULL });
return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Added full code.

Comment: could we see your code?

Comment: `strdup` isn't standard function.

Comment: your makefile and the error output do not match (`-g`, `-o test` vs. `-o tester`).  please show the actual code

Comment: Both of those warnings are pretty telling you neglected something in the code, which you also neglected to *post*. Vicious cycle, isn't it.

Comment: Added the failing segment of code. @ensc Right. I tried changing the output name, but it didn't help either.

Comment: @WhozCraig It works perfectly fine if I don't run make, but rather type in the command myself.

Comment: Does that segment of code appear in a .c file that includes `<string.h>` with proper macros defined to pull in [**`strdup`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Look above. As stated. Typing in "gcc test.c -o test -std=c99" produces no errors or segmentation faults during runtime.

Comment: What does `type -a gcc` say?

Comment: `type -a gcc` says: `gcc er(is) /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: OK, then you need to show what you're actually doing.

Comment: Note that neither of those are *errors*, they're warnings. What is odd is that `strdup` should be in `string.h` if compiled properly. Can you add an updated section to your question adding  `-v` to your compiler command line in your makefile? Something isn't wiring up correctly. It's almost like a *different* `string.h` (some local file or some such) is being pulled in, but only when compiled via `make`.

Comment: @WhozCraig `strdup` isn't C99, which is what `-std=c99` requests.

Comment: @melpomene I understand, but *both* cases should then produce a puking binary, and only the makefile version is doing so. The OP is passing `-std=c99` to *both* builds (assuming honesty on their part).

Comment: Think I figured somethning out. It compiles in C89 mode, but not in C99.

Comment: Changing the line `char* str_cpy = strdup(str)` with `char* str_cpy = malloc(sizeof(char*); strcpy(str_cpy, str); ` works fine with C99.

Comment: Either your makefile enables more warningsd by default than your command line does (see e.g. `CFLAGS`), or there is some toher define which disable the declaration of POSIX functions in the standard header. Check the whole makefile and the cpp output.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Nitpick: `strdup` isn't a *C* standard function. It is defined in a few other standards though. And question is tagged *gcc* so those other standards are certainly relevant.

Comment: @hyde   using the `-std=c99` option.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That doesn't *block* using `strdup()`, it just leaves required feature test macros undefined by *default*. They can be defined explicitly.

Comment: @ChristianS `char* str_cpy = malloc(sizeof(char*); strcpy(str_cpy, str);` --> `char* str_cpy = malloc(strlen(str)+1); strcpy(str_cpy, str);`

Comment: @hyde Nitpick ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) is defined a bunch of standards (SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001), but not the C standard. If you specify `-std=c99`, *gcc* by default disables functions defined in these standards. The warning about "implicit declaration" is because C has (annoying) legacy feature of declaring functions implicitly, if you just call them, with certain rules such as return type `int`, which in this case doesn't match your assignment to `char*`. These warnings are something you should *always* fix.

In this case, with `-std=c99`, it can be fixed by using [*feature test macros*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

The linked manual page tells in which cases the function declaration will be included, so for example this will build it without problems:

```
gcc test.c -o test -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
```

or with *gcc* you can use this, which enables pretty much all the features of the libc.

```
gcc test.c -o test -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

You could also add the define in the *.c* file as normal `#define` *before* you include the relevant system headers. It may be better to have it at the same place as the `-std=c99` though (ie. command line option), because here it kinda goes together with that.

---

A more extreme solution would be to switch to `-std=gnu99`. But think carefully about doing that, because then it is easy to accidentally use *language* features which aren't standard C. And then you will run into much more porting trouble, than just writing a few functions, if you need to port the software to other C compiler which doesn't have GNU extensions.

Answer (score -1):

If you ask gcc for C99 compliant code, it will do as you asked and forget it ever knew about `strdup()`- This function is not covered by the C99 standard, but is rather POSIX only, so `strdup` is nowhere in a header file in C99 mode.

As your code doesn't see the prototype for that reason, and doesn't know `strdup ()` will return a pointer but rather assumes an integer, it might do all sorts of havoc when 32-/64- mixed mode code where `(sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*))` is generated.

Simple remedy: Don't try to use `strdup` in c99 mode.

Why you seem to see the bug when compiling using make and not otherwise, is something we cannot deduct from the information you have provided. I guess for some reason you aren't switching gcc into c99 mode when using the command line.

Comment: You're correct. Found out it does compile without C99. That's how it goes if you don't pay proper attention ._.

Comment: @ChristianS Apparently it compiled with `-std=c99` too, otherwise where is your segfault coming from?

Comment: It came from the first call of strdup() @melpomene

Comment: @ChristianS Yes, exactly. Which is why your claims of "it doesn't compile" make no sense.